# Assigning a hash to a hash

Tags: perl, hash

Right now I have two hashes. I want to assign one entire hash to an id in a second hash. However, I am having trouble assigning that hash into the other hash.

Can you assign a hash into another hash by just saying:

```
$nodes{$id}=%nodeHash;
```

Right now this doesn't work because when I say:

```
print Dumper(\%nodes);
```

I get this as a result:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'c2' => '4/8',
      'c1' => {}
    };
```

Sorry if this doesn't totally make sense, I am not a very experienced programmer so a hash of hashes is pretty complex.

Comment: perlreftut perlreftut perlreftut

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Aggregates only store scalars.  So use the ref operator to take a ref to the hash:

```
$nodes{$id} = \%node_hash;
```

or, sometimes slightly more safely, allocating a new one and copying the old one into it, then returning the new reference:

```
$nodes{$id} = { %node_hash };
```

Comment: This is perfect. Fixed my problem!

Answer (score 8):

A hash value must be a scalar, so you need to assign a hash reference:

```
$nodes{$id} = \%nodeHash;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use a hash as the value, but you can use a reference to the hash; `$nodes{$id} = \%nodeHash;`